# pandas dataframe: replace (standalone) substring in cell based on dict

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dictionary

I'm wondering if someone in the community could help with the following:

Aim to regex replace substrings in a pandas DataFrame (based on a dictionary I pass as argument). Though the **key:value replacement should only take place**, if the dict **key is found as a standalone substring** (not as part of a word). By standalone substring I mean it starts after a whitespace

e.x:

```
mapping = {

   "sweatshirt":"sweat_shirt",
   "sweat shirt":"sweat_shirt",
   "shirt":"shirts"

}

df = pd.DataFrame([
         ["men sweatshirt"]
         ["men sweat shirt"]
         ["yellow shirt"]
       ])

df = df.replace(mapping,regex=True)
```

expected result:
substring "shirt" within sweatshirt should NOT be replaced with "shirts" as value is part of another string not a standalone value(\b)

NOTE:
the dictionary I pass is rather long so ideally there is a way to pass the standalone requirement (\b) as part of the dict I pass onto `df.replace(dict, regex=True)`

Thanks upfront

Comment: Apart from including whitespace in the mapping use df = df.apply(lambda x: ' '+x, axis=1).replace(mapping,regex=True).ID.str.strip()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
df[0].str.replace(fr"\b(?:{'|'.join([x for x in mapping])})\b", lambda x: mapping[x.group()])
```

The regex will look like `\b(?:sweatshirt|shirt)\b`, it will match `sweatshirt` or `shirt` as whole words. The match will be passed to a lambda and the corresponding value will be fetched using `mapping[x.group()]`.

**Multiword Search Term Update**

Since you may have multiword terms to search in the `mapping` keys, you should make sure the longest search terms come first in the alternation group. That is, `\b(?:abc def|abc)\b` and not `\b(?:abc|abc def)\b`.

```
import pandas as pd

mapping = {
   "sweat shirt": "sweat_shirt",
   "shirt": "shirts"
}

df = pd.DataFrame([
         ["men sweatshirt"],
         ["men sweat shirt"]
       ])
rx = fr"\b(?:{'|'.join(sorted([x for x in mapping],key=len,reverse=True))})\b"
df[0].str.replace(rx, lambda x: mapping[x.group()])
```

Output:

```
0     men sweatshirt
1    men sweat_shirt
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: wondering if your code above does also consider substrings that are at the very beginning of the cell value e.x. ^shirt 123? thanks

Comment: @Mirko Yes, `\b`, when followed with a "word" char (digit, letter or `_`), also matches at the start of the string.

Comment: got one final question (sorry to bother Wiktor). had some edge cases where the repl. didnt work. to stick to the ex. I had given in the initial post. lets say Id have a df with value `men sweat shirt` and the following mapping `"sweat shirt: "sweat_shirt", "shirt": "shirts" `. Im not sure whether key1:value1 or key2:value2 would actually take effect. it seems in 9/10 cases key1:value1 is replace, but not always. you able to tell if the dict used in the mapping is processed from top to bottom so I can add those keys with space before those keys without? any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Include the white-space in your pattern! :)

```
mapping = {

   " sweatshirt":" sweat_shirt",
   " shirt":" shirts"

}

df = ([
         ["men sweatshirt"]
       ])

df = df.replace(mapping,regex=True)
```

Comment: This will not replace the string if the string to replace is at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-

```
mapping = {

   " sweatshirt":" sweat_shirt",
   " shirt":" shirts"
}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame ({'ID':["men sweatshirt", "black shirt"]}
       )

df = df.apply(lambda x: ' '+x, axis=1).replace(mapping,regex=True).ID.str.strip()
print(df)
```